# update data in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

my code update is not working. i have some code in controller

```
function update($id) {
    $this->load->model("Model_mahasiswa");
    $data['nim']=$_POST['nim'];
    $data['nama']=$_POST['nama'];
    $data['alamat']=$_POST['alamat'];
    $result=$this->Model_mahasiswa->edit($id, $data);
    if($result){
        header("location: http://localhost/si_akademik/index.php/mahasiswa/");
    }
}
```

and in modal code

```
public function edit($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $result = $this->db->update('mahasiswa', $data); 

    return $result;
}
```

but error: Call to a member function edit() on a non-object
can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: What is your model file name ? Its `model_mahasiswa.php` ?

Comment: yes.. model_mahasiswa.php

Comment: try `$this->load->model("model_mahasiswa");` instead of `$this->load->model("Model_mahasiswa");`

Comment: its not working, and find Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mahasiswa::model()

Comment: What is the class name of the model? Which folder is it placed under?

Comment: is it in model folder?

Comment: `function edit() on a non-object` means the function `edit` has been called on a NON-OBJECT. Which means the model hasn't been initialized properly. The call `$this->load->model("Model_mahasiswa");` fails somehow, either inproper classname, or it's not found inside the models folder.

Comment: Use `$this->load->model("model_mahasiswa");` for `$this->load->model("Model_mahasiswa");` and  `$result=$this->model_mahasiswa->edit($id, $data);` for `$result=$this->Model_mahasiswa->edit($id, $data);`

Comment: and the file name should be in small letters. ie, `model_mahasiswa`

Answer (score 0):

Modify you model function :

```
public function edit($id, $data)
{
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $result = $this->db->update('mahasiswa', $data); 

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: its not working and find Fatal error: Call to a member function edit() on a non-object